# Why do I get different results when calling gmock EXPECT_CALL with Times(n) on stack objects and heap objects?

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

I want to use gmock EXPECT_CALL with Times(n) in my code. I wrote a sample test and ***got wrong results*** when calling on *objects created using new keyword.*  But it worked accurately with stack objects. 
Since I am planning to use heap objects in my real testing, I need to know what I am doing wrong here.
Here is my sample code.

```
#include <gmock/gmock.h>
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

class Point
{
private:
    int x;
    int y;

public:
    Point(int a, int b)
    {
        this->x = a;
        this->y = b;
    }

    virtual int getSum()
    {
        return x + y;
    }
};

class MockPoint :
        public Point
{
public:
    MockPoint(int a, int b):Point(a,b){}

    MOCK_METHOD0(getSum, int());
};

class PointTests :
        public ::testing::Test
{
};

TEST_F(PointTests, objectTest)
{
    MockPoint p(10, 20);
    EXPECT_CALL(p, getSum()).Times(10);
    p.getSum();
}

TEST_F(PointTests, pointerTest)
{
    MockPoint* p = new MockPoint(10,20);
    EXPECT_CALL(*p, getSum()).Times(10);
    p->getSum();
}
```

I expect to fail both the tests because I call getSum() only one time.

But here are the results I actually get when running the test.

```
[ RUN      ] PointTests.objectTest
/home/lasantha/test/PointTests.cpp:44: Failure
Actual function call count doesn't match EXPECT_CALL(p, getSum())...
         Expected: to be called 10 times
           Actual: called once - unsatisfied and active
[  FAILED  ] PointTests.objectTest (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] PointTests.pointerTest
[       OK ] PointTests.pointerTest (0 ms)
[----------] 2 tests from PointTests (0 ms total)
```

Comment: You never delete mock point allocated on the heap, so I'm assuming it does not report results properly. Also point lacks virtual destructor and it seems that virtual method is only added for testing purposes.

Comment: Thank you. Not deleting the heap object was the problem. After adding virtual destructor and deleting the object solved the problem. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must delete MockPoint to check conditions:

```
TEST_F(PointTests, pointerTest)
{
    MockPoint* p = new MockPoint(10,20);
    EXPECT_CALL(*p, getSum()).Times(10);
    p->getSum();
    **delete(p);**
}
```